# How can I difference each element among list of list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, difference

I am trying to write a python code and I have a list of list like as below:
[[1],[1,2],[3,4],[3],[4,5,6],[2,5,7,8]]
I want to use each element for difference above element, for example: the first element will difference with itself and the second will difference the first element the third element will difference the first element and second element etc.

```
first= list(set([1]).difference(set([1)))
second= list(set([1,2]).difference(set([1)))
third= list(set([3,4]).difference(set([1,2])).difference(set([1])))
Fourth= list(set([3]).difference(set([3,4])).difference(set([1,2])).difference(set([1])))
```

and the "return" will [first,second,third,Fourth........]

Does any one have any idea? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly changed the implementation suggested by @OmarAflak in the comments. Reusing the intermediate results will not work in case the intermediate result is an empty list `[]`, to overcome this I have a set `prev` that keeps track of all the elements seen so far.

```
def difference(seq):
    res = []
    prev = set(seq[0])
    for i in seq:
        res.append(list(set(i).difference(prev)))
        prev.update(i)
    return res

seq =  [[1],[1,2],[3,4],[3],[4,5,6],[2,5,7,8]]
res = difference(seq)
print(res)

seq =  [[1],[1,2],[3,4],[3],[4,5,6],[2,5,7,8], [1, 2, 18], [9]]
res = difference(seq)
print(res)
```

Output

```
[[], [2], [3, 4], [], [5, 6], [8, 7]]
[[], [2], [3, 4], [], [5, 6], [8, 7], [18], [9]]
```

Comment: This code can be optimized since you keep calculating the same differences over and over. Basically you can make n calls to `difference()` by reusing the result of the previous iteration, you are doing n*(n-1)/2 calls. (n being the size of the list)

Comment: I see, I will try if I can find a way to reduce the calls

Comment: @OmarAflak can you check this?

Comment: Indeed that's better in terms of complexity. Well done ;)